# Redux load initial data from local file and later from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

I have created one Todo App using React, Redux, Saga. However, on app load I am getting data from my local file but when I modify any task and update it, its get updated in state but when I refresh its again loading from the local file.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Below is my local data in data.js

```
let todos = [
{
  id: 0.11,
  name: 'Apple'
}]
```

Below is my reducer :-

```
import todos from "./data";

const appReducer = (state = todos, action) => {
 let newTodos;
 switch (action.type) {
 case "ADD_TODO_SAGA": {
  newTodos = [...state];
  newTodos.push(action.payload);
  return newTodos;
 }
})
```

Kindly help

Comment: You have to modify `data.js` every time you modify state if you want to get the last values.

Comment: you mean I have to write my data.js file every time? Will it be good idea? or any other way available?

Comment: Another option is to have a backend and save the data inside the database. If you cannot do that and your app is simple you can use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh or close the tab, the state in your redux will be destroyed.
you can achieve this both with localStorage and redux.
each time you update redux, you should update localStorage as well.
for each mount of project(componentDidMount) you should fill your redux with data stored in localStorage

Answer (score 0):

- Your app reducer loading data from the ./data file.
- This is your initial state when the application gets bootstrap.
- If you wish to persist data and on every refresh and same data should get reflected then use cookie store to persist it.

1. Instead of loading data from ./data file directly
   a. Create a getInitialState function.
   b. Try to load the data from cookies/cache.
   c. if required cookies are found then return that data.
   d. If no cookies are found then return the data from the ./data file
2. Apart from fetching you also need to store the state in cache.
   So on every redux update write the state in the cookie/cache

Answer (score -1):

befor :

```
case "ADD_TODO_SAGA": {
  newTodos = [...state];
  newTodos.push(action.payload);
  return newTodos;
 }
```

after :

```
     case "ADD_TODO_SAGA": {
          state = [...state,
          action.payload
];                
         }
```